# How to use Read More Toggle for dynamic Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With my Rating Compnent the user can write text about some product. Now when the user writes more than three lines, the component should show only 3 lines and add `Read More toggler` sothat somebody can read the whole text by clicking on the `Read More href`. See  http://jsfiddle.net/71w7tagr/2/ How to add Read More Toggler when the text is longer than 3 lines?

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle link

Comment: You can use a jQuery plugin dotdotdot ..http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by three lines.  If you're talking about paragraph tags or the number of characters, it's relatively simple.  Just count them and if it's higher than your desired value, hide the extra.

```
var children = $('.text_container').children('p');

if ( children.length > 3 ){
    children.slice(2).hide();
    children.slice(2,3).after('Read More Markup');
}
```

Then just add a listener to the 'Read More' text that will show all of the children.

Comment: The div does not have any paragraph. How to do it in case of characters?